# Fail to open connection #Error Rdlc Custom Code

Tags: rdlc

m in a big trouble please help...I have Rdlc report the expression is using custom code which has Connection string but when i run the report it doesnt work :(
the connection is failed to open. this is so far i have done :

My custom Rdlc code here..

```html
    Function GradeCal(ByVal SubDivID As Integer, ByVal Perc As Decimal) As String
        Dim oConn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        oConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=PSIDB; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=*******"
        oConn.Open()
        Dim oCmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        oCmd.Connection = oConn
        oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from dbo.[funcGradesCal](" + SubDivID + "," + Perc + ")"
      
        Dim nRetVal As String = oCmd.ExecuteScalar()
        oConn.Close()
        If (nRetVal <> Nothing) Then
            Return nRetVal
        Else
            Return "0-0"
        End If
    End Function
```

and here its my my expression...

```html
=Code.GradeCal(1,42)
```

but it results #Error :(

i have added refernece in custom code..
System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Please give me any idea

Answer (score 0):

Embedding connection string in custom code will result in deployment nightmares.

A better approach would be to create a report parameter with default value of `"0-0"`, fetch data `Dim nRetVal As String = oCmd.ExecuteScalar()` at time of calling the report and assign the report parameter with the `nRetVal`.

**Update**

1. Move your function `GradeCal()` from the report to another class or module
2. Open your report in design view
3. Define a report parameter

   - Select **View** -> **Report Data** from the menu
   - Right click **Parameters** and click on **Add Parameter...**
   - Assign a name to your parameter: `GradeCal`4.
   - Optionally set a Default value for the parameter
4. Modify your report item from `=Code.GradeCal(1,42)` to `=Parameters!GradeCal.Value` or just drag and drop the parameter onto the report.
5. In your program call your function `dim nRetVal as integer = GradeCal(1,42)` to fetch data
6. Pass value to parameter report

   `Dim param As New ReportParameter("GradeCal",nRetVal)`
   `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param)`

Comment: But Custome code function has one of the parameter that runs in expression at run time of report...so how wud i assign expr to =code.GradCal(,) ??

Comment: GradeCal(1,42) The param 42 will be comes from expression which is calculating on runtime of report...